# Алгоритм перевода арабские цифр в римские, без if

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Придумал алгоритм перевода арабских в римские без условий `if`.
Аналогов в интернете не нашёл. Как вам такой вариант?

```js
function myFunction()
{
  let r = [["I","V"],["X","L"],["C","D"],["M",""]];
  let f = [[],[[0,1,0]],[[0,2,0]],[[0,3,0]],[[0,1,1],[0,1,0]],[[0,1,1]],
          [[0,1,0],[0,1,1]],[[0,2,0],[0,1,1]],[[0,3,0],[0,1,1]],[[1,1,0],[0,1,0]]];
  let num = document.getElementById("num").value; let rim = "";

  String(num).split("").reverse().forEach((element, i) =>  
     f[element].forEach((d) => 
         rim = rim.concat (r[i+d[0]][d[2]].repeat(d[1]))));
      
  console.log(rim.split("").reverse().join(""));
}
```

```html
Перевод арабские в римские
<input type="number" id="num">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Перевод</button>
```

Comment: А для чего нужен `f`?

Comment: У вас при входном значении 0 - ответ -пустое поле. В римских цифрах вроде нет обозначения 0, но и пустого поля в ответе тоже не должно быть

Comment: для Стаса: это базовый алгоритм. Понятно что не проверяется максимальное число (3999) для римских и нет проверки на 0, отрицательные значения и т.д. Тут про концепцию а не детали.

Comment: по коду: вместо reduce используется foreach, есть лишний split

Comment: да и reverse в принципе не нужен

Answer (score 6):

```
let num = "927";
```

Вся концепция алгоритма строится на том, что если число разбить на порядки, то для каждого числа в отдельном порядке будет одна и так же формула подстановки из арабского числа в римские.

Так, для числа 927, мы получает 9 - третьего порядка, 2 - второго порядка, 7 первого порядка.

```
let m = [
    ["I","V"], // 1 порядок
    ["X","L"], // 2 порядок
    ["C","D"], // 3 порядок
    ["M",""]]; // 4 порядок
```

Далее, если взять любое число из любого порядка, для 927 это 9 или 2 или 7, или для любого числа от 1 до 9, то можно написать универсальные формулы

Точнее 9 универсальных формул:

где P - порядок числа, r - повтор (сколько раз этот символ нужно повторить), и M - место в массиве порядка первое или второе

Тогда формулы чисел можно представить как:

```
1 - P.r(1).M(1)                 
2 - P.r(2).M(1)
3 - P.r(3).M(1)
4 - P.r(1).M(1) + P.r(1).M(2)
5 - P.r(1).M(2)
6 - P.r(1).M(2) + P.r(1).M(1)
7 - P.r(1).M(2) + P.r(2).M(1)
8 - P.r(1).M(2) + P.r(3).M(1)
9 - P.r(1).M(1) + P+1.r(1).M(1)
```

Наше число 927 преобразуется по формулам

```
9 (P=3) : P.r(1).M(1) + P+1.r(1).M(1), , состоит из двух частей
    1 часть: P.r(1).M(1), где P=3: ["C","D"], место 1, повторов 1. Значит: C
    2 часть: P+1.r(1).M(1), где P=4 (так как P+1): ["M",""], место 1, повторов 1, значит: M

2 (P=2) : P.r(2).M(1), где P=2: ["X","L"], место 1, повторов 2, значит: ХХ

7:(P=1) : P.r(1).M(2) + P.r(2).M(1), состоит из двух частей
        1 часть: P.r(1).M(2), где P=1: ["I","V"], место 2, повторов 1. Значит: V
        2 часть: P.r(2).M(1), где P=1: ["I","V"], место 1, повторов 2, значит: II
```

И теперь эти формулы можно зашить в массив для каждого числа.
Например для числа 6 - это 6 элемент массива f

```
[0,1,0], [0,1,1]
```

То есть два элемента
Где каждая часть - это формула для набора символов

Первый символ: [0,1,0]

3 элемента:

```
1 - порядок 
2 - количество повторов символа
3 - место в массиве "m" к примеру: ["X","L"] - 1 или 2 место
```

Сама формула работает так:

1. разбиваем число на массив из символов 927 -> [9,2,7]
2. делаем реверс [9,2,7]->[7,2,9], так как первый порядок актуален для первого элемента
3. В цикле берём отдельное число 9, 2 или 7, по этому числу берём формулу в массиве f, и разбираем вторым циклом группу формул, чтобы взять отдельный блок формулы (например [0,1,0]), и уже этот блок нам скажет какой символ брать из массив "m", его место и количество повторов

   ```
   num.split("").reverse().forEach((e, i) => f[e].forEach((d) => r = r.concat (m[i+d[0]][d[2]].repeat(d[1]))));
   ```

   собираем в обратном порядке строку и выводим результат.

   ```
   alert (r.split("").reverse().join(""));
   ```

Ну и неминифицированная формула

```
num.split("").reverse().forEach((element, i) => 
{
    // element - элемент из числа 9 2 или 7
    formula = f[element];
    // для числа 7 = [[0,2,0],[0,1,1]]
    // тут 2 элемента массива по 3 числа, теперь нужно перебрать их

    formula.forEach((d) => 
    {
        // первый элемент для числа 7 - [0,2,0]
        // вытащим 3 элемента
        poradok = d[0];  // 0
        povtor = d[1];   // 2
        mesto = d[2];    // 0

        simbolMas = m[i+poradok]; // ["I","V"]
        findsimbol =  simbolMas[mesto] // "I"
        simbolRepeat = findsimbol.repeat(povtor); //  "II"  
        r = r.concat (  simbolRepeat ); // собираем строчку
    })
});
```